# SQL Selecting consecutive rows with rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, rownum

Trying to create some test data via script, populating TableA.colVal with ID's that don't yet exist in TableB.

The end result is to see that all of TableA.colVal 's eventually populate into TableB.ID_PK:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (colVal , aPK2, aPK3) VALUES
(
  (SELECT colVal , aPK2, aPK3
    FROM tableA
    WHERE colVal   NOT IN   
    (   
       SELECT bID_PK
        FROM (SELECT bID_PK, rownum r
           FROM (SELECT bID_PK
                  FROM TableB order by bID_PK DESC)
            )
         where r = 1  -- 
       )
     and rownum = 1)
  );
```

So if 
    TableA  has colVals 1,2,5,6,7,8
and
    TableB  has bID_PKs 1,5,7

specifically I would like to identify the 'missing' 3 
    TableB.bID_PK values : 2, 6 and 8

I tried incrementing r = 1, in hopes of getting the next value to populate, but I am always getting the 1st TableA.colVal that is not found in TableB (so all my TableA.colVal 's are getting the same value).  Changing the rownum for the outer select doesn't work either.

Help?

**clarification**
I need to populate TableA.colVal  with TableB.bID_PK values that don't yet exist in TableA.colVal , where TableA has a 3-field compound Primary Key.  I can manually change the values of the remaining PK fields, but I need to populate the remaining field with the value from TableB.bID_PK (which is TableB's primary key).

Comment: The `values` clause is wrong if you want the source of the `insert` to be a `select` statement: `INSERT INTO tableA (colVal , aPK2, aPK3) select ...`

Answer (score 1):

The `select` you want looks like:

```
select b.id
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.aid = b.bid);
```

You can insert into an existing table using `insert` or create a new table using the appropriate syntax for your database.

Comment: Because TableA has a compound Primary Key, I can't do a bulk insert as your solution prescribes.  I have to insert 10-20 rows into TableA where TableA.ID does not yet have an entry in TableB.ID.

Comment: @frododot . . . Can you ask another question with sample data and desired results?  I think this question is unclear, and it is simpler to just start over.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a good use case for EXCEPT:

```
INSERT INTO TableA ({Primary Key Columns})
SELECT {Primary Key Columns} FROM TableB
EXCEPT
SELECT {Primary Key Columns} FROM TableA
```